# To convert the WHILE loop query into FOR loop query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

This is the table created and inserted values into it in SQL server

```
create table Country (
id int, countryname varchar(25)
)
insert into country (id, countryname) 
values (1,'India'), (2,'Austria'), (3,'Sri Lanka'), (4,'Mongolia'), (5,'Russia')
```

And using WHILE loop, I achieved the below query in SQL Server.

```
declare @id int, @countryname varchar(30), @maxid int
select @id=min(id), @maxid=max(id)
from country
while(@id is not null and @id<=@maxid)
begin
select @countryname=`countryname`    
from Country where id=@id
print convert`(varchar,@id)`+'. country name is '+ @countryname
set @id=@id+1
end
```

Now I want the same above result with the usage of FOR loop, I know in SQL server FOR loop is not used, but with WHILE loop we can simulate the FOR loop in SQL server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Loops are almost never appropriate for SQL.  You can do the above using a query, which I highly recommend (except for the `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a query, not a loop with `print`:**

In SQL we always try to work on sets at once, and not use `while` loops or cursors.

```sql
select
    concat(convert(varchar(12), @id), '. country name is ', countryname)
from Country
order by id
```